# Check time range on different days

Tags: vb.net

I have a start and end date as in the following example:

```
Dim start as DateTime = "26-07-2017 21:36:40"
Dim [end] as DateTime = "27-07-2017 06:35:37"
```

I want to check if 02: 24H exists in this time range (in this case exists).
This would be easy if the beginning and the end were on the same day but what is the simplest and most effective way of doing this verification in cases where a change of day occurs?

Comment: You only have the time, `02:24`, and you want to know if that time occurs at least once between two given moments, regardless of on what day that happens and how many times?

Comment: More or less, in this case in this time range will only occur once (I'm working in the 24H format), but for example if the time was 18:40 would no longer occur. I want to know how I verify that this time (02:24) will occur in this range. I hope I was explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function TimeExists(ByVal start As DateTime, ByVal [end] As DateTime, ByVal time As TimeSpan) As Boolean
    'You only need to check two days: the 'start' day and the 'start + 1' day

    Select Case start.Date + time
        Case start To [end] : Return True
    End Select

    Select Case start.Date.AddDays(1) + time
        Case start To [end] : Return True
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! And by the way, how would I get the DateTime complete with Day 27 and Time 02:24?

Comment: @BrunoGomes Apparently you return the expression being `select case`'d instead of returning `true`.

Comment: Got it. Thank's!